# Video Thumbnail generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, thumbnails

i am currently exploring on how to create thumbnail from video file. so far, i am able to generate thumbnail using ffmpeg but can somebody suggest me if there any other ways to generate thumbnail without involving executable(.exe) file.

Thanks,
New Learner, Please guide me...

Comment: I think, you have already found the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[ffmpeg.exe](http://ffmpeg.org/)** is the best solution for Video Thumbnails generation as it is free software licensed under the LGPL or GPL.

There are few other places where you will find the solution:

[C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library)

[DirectShow .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/)

[SlimDX is a free open source framework that enables developers to easily build DirectX applications using .NET technologies such as C#](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a generic thumbnail an easy way to get one is through the WindowsAPICodePack.Shell package.  A small, medium, large, or extra large thumbnail can be generated.  There's not as much control over the output as ffmpeg but it's hard to beat this method when a generic thumbnail will do or when avoiding an outside exe.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using System.Drawing;

namespace GetVideoThumbnail
{
    class VideoThumbnail
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string videoPath = @"C:\Users\NotSure\Desktop\SampleVideo.MP4";

            // Create shell object
            ShellObject videoShellObject = ShellObject.FromParsingName(videoPath);

            // Create bitmap and/or save locally
            Bitmap thumbnailBmp = videoShellObject.Thumbnail.LargeBitmap;
            thumbnailBmp.Save(@"C:\Users\NotSure\Desktop\SampleVideoThumbnail.bmp");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea!,good this interestingly Q.
I worked it issue,my diploma tasking-at Uni.

And more yet Articles.

1.[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) - This Open source project Best worked C/C++,C# and Java

2.[Emg CV](http://www.emgu.com) - This good worked C#

, and more...

Try it's open sources.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the VideoFileReader from [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/), specifically `AForge.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileReader`. It makes use of ffmpeg DLLs.

Alternatively, on Windows 7, you could use `ShellFile.Thumbnail` from WindowsAPICodePack or use DirectShow to save a frame with VideoRenderer.

I recently used the ShellFile method, with VideoFileReader as backup.